Soldiers hunted by tribe in jungle, possibly 1970's
Saw this film many years ago and after asking friends, colleagues and doing several net searches I still can't think of the title. It probably isn't as good as I remember it any way but I hope you guys can help.
I remember vaguely these parts: (although may have a few small details wrong)

A group of soldiers (US I think) are doing a training exercise in a big forest/jungle. 
They stray from the group and there is about 5 of them.
They kill some tribe person who I think was armed with a rifle and wearing some animal fur, I think this part took place near a river or when they were crossing a river.
The soldiers search his shack/home/shed thing for supplies and end up burning it down or blowing it up.

The rest is a bit of a blur now until the end but I assume there slowly getting taken out by these tribe people

2 remaining soldiers end up in a village and they are still getting hunted by some tribes people in the village (I think a lot of the villagers were friendly) and I am sure there was a pig involved??
1 or maybe 2 of the remaining soldiers escape in a truck (after a few close combat scenes inside the villagers' houses) and I am sure 1 of them was badly wounded.

That's all I can remember. Probably some of this I am remembering from other films. Which is why I guess I need to see this one again.
Also I think it was released some time in the 70's.
Thank you for your help. Give me your suggestions and I will look them up on imdb. Give your self a pat on the back if you guess it correctly.

Sounds like Walter Hill's Southern Comfort with Keith Carradine from 1981. In this movie, that's a little reminiscent of Deliverance:

A squad of National Guards on an isolated weekend exercise in the Louisiana swamp must fight for their lives when they anger local Cajuns by stealing their canoes.

They burn down the shack of one of the Cajun hunters, and caged pigs (and a slaughtered pig) figure into the plot at some point. In the end, only 2 of them (1 injured) manage to escape when they reach the village and spot an army truck. The trailer, as well as the entire movie, are available on Youtube.
